# XUL listbox.insertItemAt fails after several opening and closings

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have a sidebar extension that I'm working on. The problem I'm encountering is that when that sidebar is opened, it goes through some initialization. This requires populating a list. I have an object, which has some of the following functionality:

```
 var intializeSidear = {
 initSidebar: function(){
 var listbox_to_init = document.getElementById('generic-list-box'); 
 for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 listbox_to_init.appendItem("Test", i);
 }
 }
 ....
```

What happens is the first time I open the sidebar, everything works fine. The next time I open it, it gives the error that "listbox_to_init.appendItem is not a function." (I have it wrapped in a try/catch block).

Is there any reason for why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that in order for this to fire correctly, an event listener needs to be tied to the window load event:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function load(event){
window.removeEventListener("load", load, false); //remove listener, no longer needed
    init();
},false);
```

I'm unsure why this is though. When I alerted the variable that I retrieved from document.getElementById() on the listbox, it showed it as being a [Xul Object], which it is. So why could it make that determination, but in order to actually manipulate the xul object I needed to wait for the window to load?

If anyone has an explanation to offer, that'd be grand. In the meantime, I'll try researching and returning back here if there are still issues with my code or no one else answers my new question.